# What does EQU do functionaly in this code?

Tags: assembly, dos

I am trying to decipher what this file in an old DOS program is actually doing.

```
 IDATE  EQU I/1/8/0                    Date : MM/DD/YY
       ITIME  EQU I/9/8/0                    Time : HH:MM:SS
       IUSER  EQU I/17/6/0                User ID : XXX999
       ITERM  EQU I/23/4/0            Terminal ID : ST99
       KAREA  EQU K/1/64/0
```

I had thought that `EQU` was an operator asking " is equal to ".  I cannot seem to figure out what its use it here.

Are the strings that look like "`I/1/8/0`" or "`K/1/64/0`" actually values that are being compared to the `ITIME` and `KAREA` variables or are they pointing to some location where data is being stored?

Some other lines further down in the file:

```
     FUNITM EQU X/3001/013/0
   F0     EQU W/3001/013/0/    000000000
   F1     EQU *13/0/ASM 000103000
   F2     EQU *13/0/ASM,000103000
   F3     EQU *13/0/JCR 000104000
   F4     EQU *13/0/JCRR000104000
   F5     EQU *13/0/JVR 000104000
```

I wish I knew the right words to google how this works...  Any clues would be great. Thank you

Here is another piece of a file in the program that may be an indicator of what this is written in:

```
       RMK     Cash receipts listing in Alpha sequence
       RMK
       RMK
       RMK     ***** Data Definition *****
       RMK     ***** File I/O Area is 1024 bytes *****
       RMK           "A" Record in SCRN File contains 8 numbers from 01-98
       RMK            (99 is reserved as the null file pointer)
       RMK            in positions 11-12, 13-14, ... 25-26 where 11-12
       RMK            establishes the physical location of file #1,
       RMK            13-14 file #2 ... 25-26 file #8 as referenced in this
       RMK            source code module.
       RMK            These numbers (01-98) point to the physical file
       RMK            assignments for files #1 thru #8 used in this source
       RMK            file.
       RMK            The actual physical locations of these files (01-98)
       RMK            appear in positions 3 thru 25 in records 1-98 in the
       RMK            STxx\FILES.REF file.
       RMK
       RMK     (I/O Area Definitions)
IAREA  EQU I/1/1024/0     The "I" area position 1 for a length 1024
       RMK
       RMK     (File #1 I/O Area Definition)
       CPY /DB\CHK/
       RMK
       RMK     (File #2 I/O Area Definition)
       CPY /DB\CST/
```

Comment: this is not "DOS" programming it is some language.  My guess is it is similar to a define in C, but you have not provided enough context or a language or toolchain or anything like that.

Comment: What @dwelch said. `EQU` is a valid comparison operator in DOS, but the commands you posted are not valid DOS command instructions (at least not native instructions)

Comment: A file extension would help. They look kind of like some kind of structure definitions.  The 8, 6, 4 and 64 seem like field lengths.  And the 1, 9, 17 23 would be starting offsets for each of the fields.

Comment: I'd say this is 8086 assembly language for some macro-assembler like Microsoft's MASM or Borland's TASM. While I've never looked into it a lot, for what I remember `EQU` was indeed similar to `#define` in C.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments; most files in this program do not seem to have extensions.  There are a .BAT and .DAT and some .PIF but I had assumed this was a DOS program because the folks who handed me the files to figure out thought it was.

Comment: It looks like some mainframe oriented programming or job control language, the kind where things had to be in certain columns. Googling for the keywords RMK, CPY and EQU doesn't turn up anything so it appears to be a very obscure language. It may be custom designed for some specific application. It's not assembly language, and the code is just a bunch of comments and data definitions. It doesn't actually do anything. If it's all stuff like this, it's probably a job control language (but not IBM JCL) and the actual code that does stuff is written in some other language.

Comment: If 'mainframe' doesn't fit, I have one other thought: It could be something for a programmable device (cash register, etc).  Maybe it got coded/built on a dos machine and downloaded to a device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I have never seen EQU used like that, those look like some sort of field or structure definitions.

Starting on the IDATE line:

```
I - Integer type.
1 - Offset of the 'IDATE' field.
8 - Length of the 'IDATE' field.
0 - ???  Perhaps # of decimal places?
```

If we take the offset of IDATE and add its length, that brings us to 9, which is the offset on the ITIME line.  Likewise for IUSER, ITERM and KAREA.

Apparently this is related to btrieve data.  I used btrieve (many years ago), and never saw tables defined using this type of syntax.  More commonly people used a DDF file (see [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/113877) for example).  Might be something to look for if you are still having difficulties parsing the data.

Comment: Thank you for the extra .DDF example info

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, thank you all for your comments; it helped steer me in the right direction;

It turned out that `EQU` was being used to create database table definitions for a `BTRIEVE` database.

Gladly then, I could easily manipulate the data via the `BUTIL` utility and write a few scripts to split the partial binary `.DAT` files into comma separated columns.

Special Thanks to  David Wohlferd (If you post an answer concerning the structure definitions, I will mark it as accepted).